# Write a shell script to show alert when there are more than 50 rows in mysql table

Tags: mysql, linux, database, shell, scripting

I have a table in MySQL and I want to show an alert or a message that tells me if my records are more than 50 rows.

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: For learning purppose

Comment: The reason may have a material impact on the chosen strategy

Comment: It's recommended that you showcase what you tried, and where you got an error (thus need help). Asking blank questions like this aren't really appreciated by the members!

Comment: Sorry about that btw and this was my first post I'll take care in it the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run a query to count the entries in the table and then use grep to parse the output.

```
 if [ $(mysql --user=<username> --password=<password> -e "select COUNT(<primary key>) from <database>.<table>" | grep -E '[[:digit:]]+') -gt "50" ];
 then 
     echo "Rows are greater then 50";
 fi
```

Comment: Show this error ./mysqlscript.sh: 19: [[: not found

Comment: What are writing the code in? bash?

Comment: Show this error ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
./mysqlscript.sh: 19: [[: not found

Comment: #!/bin/sh

mysql -u root -pflash  << EOF

use workers;
SELECT * FROM Persons;

SELECT pid,name FROM Persons WHERE gender="F";

SELECT pid,name FROM Persons WHERE gender="M";

SELECT pid FROM Persons ORDER BY pid DESC LIMIT 1;



commit;
EOF

 if [[ $(mysql -u root -p -e "select COUNT(pid) from workers.Persons" | grep -E '[[:digit:]]+') -gt "5" ]]
 then 
     echo "Rows are greater then 50"
 fi

Comment: If you are using sh, use single square brackets. I've amended the answer, please also note the semi colons. You also need to explicitly specify the password with --password  as $() will execute the mysql query in another background shell

Comment: Thanks, Ramon Sailopal that worked fine

Comment: Great. If it works, then kindly accept and up vote the solution.

Comment: Did that but apparently, I have less than 15 reputation so it just records it does not show it publicly.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh

mysql -u root -pflash  << EOF

use workers;
SELECT * FROM Persons;

SELECT pid,name FROM Persons WHERE gender="F";

SELECT pid,name FROM Persons WHERE gender="M";

SELECT pid FROM Persons ORDER BY pid DESC LIMIT 1;



commit;
EOF

 if [[ $(mysql -u root -p -e "select COUNT(pid) from workers.Persons" | grep -E '[[:digit:]]+') -gt "5" ]]
 then 
     echo "Rows are greater then 50"
 fi
```